# Error configuring Qt5 for compilation from source

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile Qt5 from source using the `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.6.tar.xz` file.  I extract the file, and create the following `qmake.conf`:

```
#
# qmake configuration for building with arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
#

MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
TARGET_PLATFORM         = unix
TEMPLATE                = app
CONFIG                  += qt warn_on release incremental link_prl gdb_dwarf_index
QT                      += core gui
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../common/linux.conf)
include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../common/g++-unix.conf)
include(../../common/qws.conf)

# Compiler Flags to take advantage of the ARM architecture
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QMAKE_LINK              = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP             = /{homedir}/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-strip

load(qt_config)
```

Next, I go inside the extracted qt folder and call `./configure` with the following parameters:

```
./configure -v -opensource -confirm-license -prefix /{homedir}/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.6 -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -embedded arm -little-endian -host-little-endian -no-qt3support -nomake demos -nomake examples -qt-gfx-linuxfb -qt-gfx-qvfb -qt-gfx-vnc -no-accessibility
```

It runs for a while then throws me this error:

```
Info: creating super cache file /{homedir}/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.6/.qmake.super
ERROR: Invalid command line parameter 'arm'.
```

Is this because of the `-embedded arm` option?  I see many pages using it so I am not sure why I am getting this error.  Please help.

Comment: Which device are you compiling for?

Comment: @Felix, it's BBB which is an ARM chip.

Comment: This wiki entry is for a raspberry, but the configure commandline (Step 10) should work for your device to, with some adjustments. Try that one and find the missing parameters. https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step

Answer (score 2):

You are probably seeing examples of how to cross-compile Qt4. Qt4 had the "-embedded arm" option, but Qt5 does not.